# How can I identify multiple word tags in a text field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tags, intersect

I would like to have a SQL procedure which can be passed a text string and it will identify specific keywords (tags) in the text from a table of keywords.

So far I have the following which works really nicely for single words;

```
INSERT INTO #tags SELECT Word 
FROM dbo.SplitWords('some colours are blue, green, red and light blue')

SELECT Word
FROM    #tags
INTERSECT
SELECT  Tag
FROM    dbo.Tags

DROP TABLE #tags
```

If my tags tables has entries for 'green', 'red' and 'blue' they are returned as you might expect.

What I would like to know is how best I can achieve a similar result but for tags which are multiple words... for example, 'light blue'

I realise the problem I have with the code above is that I am spliting the source text into individual words so 'light blue' would never match but is there a different route I could take which won't invovle cursors etc?

Thanks for your help

---

Just realized the following would achieve what I need

```
DECLARE @Text as nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Text = 'some colours are blue, green, red and light blue'

SELECT  TagID, 
    Tag 
FROM    Tags 
WHERE   @Text LIKE '% ' + Tag + ' %' 
ORDER BY Tag
```

But I'm worried it could be inefficient if my table has several thousand rows and the text string I'm searching is very long.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I could do the same process more efficiently?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to use comma separated tags.

Comment: Thanks Matt, not sure how that helps me. I already have my tags as separate rows in a table and then I have a big nvarchar(max) block of text I want to compare. I liked the idea of doing an intersect because it gives really fast results but to do that I have to split my text down to individual words.
How can I compare my text against my table rows quickly for tags with multiple words?

Comment: You might want to consider Full Text Search. See [How hard is it to incorporate full text search with SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202440/how-hard-is-it-to-incorporate-full-text-search-with-sql-server#202474)

Comment: Thanks Conrad, I agree... I've thought about Full Text search but doesn't the text you're searching have to be in a db table for it to be full text searched or can you full text search a variable in an SP?

Comment: @Mojo Can you post the solution for your question??...i have the issue

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer on [TSQL - A join using full-text CONTAINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152783/tsql-a-join-using-full-text-contains/10521704#10521704)

It leverages @Conrad's idea, but gets you past the variable restriction of CONTAINS

Comment: Tom, thanks for this unfortunately full text searching isn't an option because the nvarchar(max) field I want to search is a variable and not a full text searchable field in a db table.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I settled for my previous solution until I had time to have a re-think / wait for it to become a problem.
The old method is now taking too long to execute forcing me to find an alternative solution.

After some playing the best solution I have found (in terms of length of execution time) is to cursor it....

I therefore set up a cursor for the phrase I want to search the text for and blitz through it populating a temp table with the phrase IDs which match as I go.
Key thing to use FAST_FORWARD and FORWARD_ONLY settings to maximize performance.

Once done, I simply join my temp table back to my db tables to return whatever details of the phrases I need.

Example code below:

DECLARE @PageText nvarchar(max) -- parameter of page text

CREATE TABLE #Matches (PhraseID int)

DECLARE @PhraseID int
DECLARE @PhraseText nvarchar(100)

DECLARE curMatchingPhrases CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT  p.PhraseID,
        p.PhraseText
FROM    Phrases p

OPEN curMatchingPhrases

FETCH NEXT FROM curMatchingPhrases INTO @PhraseID, @PhraseText

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'match' WHERE @PageText LIKE '% ' + @PhraseText + ' %')
BEGIN
    INSERT #Matches SELECT  @PhraseID
    WHERE   @PhraseID NOT IN (SELECT PhraseID FROM #Matches)
END

FETCH NEXT FROM curMatchingPhrases INTO @PhraseID, @PhraseText
```

END

CLOSE curMatchingPhrases 
DEALLOCATE curMatchingPhrases

SELECT * FROM #Matches

DROP TABLE #Matches

I'm sure others on here will be able to find more elegant solutions, but the cursor has reduced a 6+sec SP down to 0 - 1sec for me, so I'm happy for now.

Mojo